# Pyspark column is not iteratable

Tags: list, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, iterable

I have a df similar to this:

```
old_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
 [   ('375', 20),
     ('265', 20),
     ('052', 20),
     ('111', None),
 ],
['old_col', 'example_new_col_val'])
```

I need to create a new column by checking the values of my old column against a list.  I'm new to Pyspark and don't understand my error message.  Here's what I've tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

my_list = ['375', '012', '013','014','015','016']
expr = F.when(F.col("old_col").isin(my_list),F.lit(20)).otherwise(None).alias("new_col")

new_df = old_df.select("*",*expr)
```

My error message: `TypeError: Column is not iterable`

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `*` in `*expr` - `expr` is a column and should not be iterated/unpacked.

```
new_df = old_df.select("*",expr)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've been doing a lot of data wrangling.  This is part of a bigger problem I'm working on.  Just trying to tackle it by breaking it down into smaller components.

Answer (score 0):

When defining `my_list`, try using:

```
my_list = list(['375', '012', '013','014','015','016'].toPandas())
```

The rest of your code remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`withColumn()`** function here in order to create a new **`column`** of your existing dataframe

**`df = df.withColumn("new_col", F.when(F.col("old_col").isin(my_list), F.lit("20")).otherwise(F.lit(None)))`**

Comment: `df.select('*', expr)` is a perfectly valid way to create a new column. In fact it's superior to `withColumn` which is known to cause performance hits. See https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015

Comment: Yeah. But I personally prefer to breakdown steps , not a grate fan of method chaining sort of thing :) But thanks for share